# array.splice(index, 1) returns array with removed item

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react hooks and I am just trying to do a simple function to remove the item from the list. To do this I am using find, indexOf, and splice.

In the onClick function, I am using the indexOf in the array.splice(indexOf, 1), BUT it returns just the item from the list. Everything rerenders and does what it is supposed to do, but the only itme that renders is the item that I just tried to delete. What am I missing?

```
const [todos, setToDo] = useState(initialToDo);
const [input, setInput] = useState('');

const todoList = (todos) => {
    return (
        todos.map((todo) => {
        return (
            <div className='todo-list flex p-2 w-1/2 justify-between'>
                <p className="px-3">{todo.name}</p>
                <button 
                    className='rounded-sm border-2 px-2'
                    onClick={(e)=>{
                        let item = todos.find(el=>el.id == todo.id);
                        console.log(item)
                        let index = todos.indexOf(item);
                        console.log(index)
                        todos = todos.splice(index, 1)
                        // todos == item
                        setToDo(todos)
                    }}    
                >-</button>
            </div>
    )}))
}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed [the documentation for `.splice()`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: `splice` returns the element(s) that was removed - not the updated array

Comment: splice gives you the element you "spliced out" splice alone does the exact opposite

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`, although it's a bit more complicated that splice. Also, `splice` modifies the original array, so just don't reassign `todos` to be the return of the `splice`, just have that be a line of its own.

Comment: @Samathingamajig is it more complicated? It does *exactly* one job and it does it exactly the same every time. Splice has at least three different effects you can use it for, if not more. The syntax you use will greatly differ depending on which one you need. And even if you call `.splice()` correctly you can still shoot yourself in the foot as the MANY questions about `.splice()` on this very site show. A very common problem is using `.splice()` in a forward loop. I'm not really sure why you consider this "simpler" or "easier".

Comment: I have reviewed the docs for splice and have replicated a solution that was given on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array

Comment: @VLAZ While splice is weird, I would say that `filter` is more complicated as it requires you to make your own callback function. Splice you just need to answer simple questions: "What index?", "How many elements do you want to remove?", and "What elements (if any) do you want to insert at the given index?". (Although I use filter way more often as it's an easier return in a one-liner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `Array.splice` returns the removed element and mutates the original array, which mean you can use `index`  to delete/update the todo from `todos` list.

Simplest way of doing this, is the following way. Here's the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2pvpzh)

```
const todoList = () => {
  const [todos, setToDo] = useState(initialToDo);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const handleDelete = index => {
    todos.splice(index, 1)
    setToDo([...todos])
  }

  return (
    todos.map((todo, index) => {
    return (
      <div className='todo-list flex p-2 w-1/2 justify-between'>
        <p className="px-3">{todo.name}</p>
        <button 
          className='rounded-sm border-2 px-2'
          onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}    
        >
        -
       </button>
      </div>
  )}))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`splice` returns the deleted items. I recommend using `filter` instead, something like:

```
setToDo(todos.filter(({ id }) => id != todo.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` instead of mutating with `splice`. Try this snippet.

```js
const TodoList = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
    { name: 'a', id: 1 },
    { name: 'b', id: 2 },
  ]);
  return todos.map((todo) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{todo.name}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setTodos(todos.filter(item => item.id !== todo.id))} > - </button>
      </div>
    );
  });
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<TodoList />, domContainer);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```